# Accessing cell text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to change the text of a table cell when only the `<table>` element has an ID, there are no IDs set on the cells, e.g.

```
<table id="test">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So how do I change the text of the second cell (Cell 2) in Javascript without explicitly specifying an ID for it?

Thanks,

AJ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's really easy to do with jQuery, but I'm assuming you want to use native DOM methods. In that case,

```
document.getElementById('test').getElementsByTagName('td')[1]
```

will get you to the 2nd table cell in that table.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Traversing_an_HTML_table_with_JavaScript_and_DOM_Interfaces

Comment: No problem. I'd still recommend using jQuery because it makes your code much more concise, reduces boilerplate, and just makes writing Javascript much less hellish.

Comment: It performs way better than my own aproach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), this task would be as simple as the following:

```
$('#test td:first').text('Your new text goes here');
```

I recommend jQuery strongly.  You'll probably get additional responses recommending jQuery as well.

Comment: Drew, the OP said second, not first.

Comment: Whoops -- missed that.  In that case, the selector would be:  '#test td:eq(1)'

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work:

```
document.getElementById('test').childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].innerHTML='changed cell';
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way for me is to do it like this code below:

```
document.getElementById("test").rows[0].cells[1].innerHTML = "Cell not so 2."
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_cells.asp

If you're dealing with a lot of data, don't use JQuery, as it is slow.

You can look at the compassion between JQuery processing and native DOM [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444882/why-is-jquery-selector-function-so-slow-compared-to-native-dom-methods) (if you follow link in that post, the page has a graph that shows how big the difference is).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pure JS with this code:

```
document.querySelector('#test td:nth-child(2)').innerHTML = 'value changed';
```

Browser support for this is pretty god: http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector

**Edit**

Unfortunately *@Matt Ball's* code is faster as you can see here: [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/traverse-table).