# Why is jQuery selector function so slow compared to native DOM methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom, getelementbyid

I know this topic has been debated in general several times already, but I am looking for a more technical and detailed insight to understand what is really going on.

I devised a series of tests to compare speed of jQuery's most basic selectors '#id' and '.class' to various native DOM methods.

What I wish is to find out exactly why the results are what they are.

Here are the tests : http://jsperf.com/jqueryspeed

The main thing noticeable, is that getElementById is clearely the fastest of all. 
To compare, I added both jQuery('#id') and jQuery.fn.init('#id') as tests, the difference between the two is that the first one does instanciate a whole new jQuery object, while the second one only runs the prototype function, and is thus faster. So, the difference between those two is understandable.

The main difference that I do NOT understand however, is the huge gap between the speed of getElementById and the speed of jQuery.fn.init, which has a simple test to handle a simple ('#id') request in a specific way, falling back to a call to getElementById itself.

So, why for example on Chrome, is this method about 8 times slower than the native one, even though it basicly is just a wrapper for it ?

It is also about 3-4 times slower than the wrapped getElementById $(document.getElementById('#id'))...

Any ideas please ?

Comment: Native methods are highly optimized, and `$.fn.init` isn't "just a wrapper" for `document.getElementById`. So why does it surprise you that there's a speed difference?

Comment: It's not just a wrapper, but it has a special test branching that leads to simply calling getElementById in the end. I'm not surprised that there is an overhead, but that the overhead is of such magnitude !

Comment: The `getElementById` is extremely fast (especially in modern browsers). So whatever overhead is there is going to be a *tiny* part of `$.fn.init`. If you walk through the code, you'll see the operations that need to take place. Clearly those operations aren't as optimized and/or are just inherently slower tasks. It's "light task" compared to "light task plus other heavier tasks".

Comment: FYI, I added a couple more tests. One is just a thin wrapper for `getElementById`. The other is a thin wrapper with a couple safety checks. They're nearly as fast as just calling the native method directly. http://jsperf.com/jqueryspeed/3

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is the amount of code jquery goes through when we use a simple ***$('selector')***

http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=init

As you can see,there are plenty of validation done,regex matches,cross browser tricks etc.

Its important to realise that jquery is a library built on javascript.Javascript executes directly on the browser.Where as jquery processes quite a lot of javascript code before being executed by the browser.

I personally prefer jquery.I am really not bothered about saving those nano seconds.The level of simplicity that jquery provides is phenomenal and an artpiece in itself.

Comment: When faced with a jQuery site *grinding* away at the DOM on some fading effect, it gives me time to contemplate. "How I wish the dev of this site **had** bothered about saving those 10^9 nanoseconds".

Comment: It's not a framework its a library. A framework defines control flow, a library is a collection of functions.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to precompile jquery to javascript if it is so bloated? Just a thought. $('#myid') shouldn't be slower than document.getElementById('myid') on an active webpage. Since they are objectively equivalent intent wise. Ok not quite since $('#myid') also needs to call $('#myid').get(0) but still, document.getElementById('x') is a mouthful, and it's somewhat expensive to say `var getElementById = document.getElementById;`

Comment: @Adria and when I'm visiting your sites with an older version of IE I wish that you've bothered implementing `getElementById` with older browsers in mind. jquery does those checks for a reason.

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing that jQuery can do as fast as native javascript and that is for a reason: it works hard to make your code cross-browser compliant and easy-to-use. It builds a jQuery object out of most method calls. In that matter, jQuery will be a lot slower than the smallest datapath required because it wants to offer features that are ready to use.

Let's compare these two "similar" calls:

**`document.getElementById("box")`**: Native method that does a simple lookup operation at a lower level than JavaScript. It then returns the DOM element that is already loaded in memory. This is one of the fastest methods.

**`$('#box')`**: Here, jQuery will begin with some parsing over what you ask it to do. For example, it will validate that it is a well-formed selector, then try to recognize what type of selector it is. Once it's done with the validation, it will try to get the element with ID "box". After then, he will create a new jQuery object, filling it with every expected attribute and making sure that all the browsers (and older browsers too) are getting the same results. This includes a lot of fallbacks and compliance tests. When the object is ready-to-use, you get the element with ID "box". Not as straightforward as `getElementById()`. When jQuery features aren't required on the targeted element, many would prefer to use `getElementById('box')` instead of `$('#box')`.

---

**UPDATE - 15/02/17:**

With jQuery >= 2.0 having no more support for the infamous IE 6/7/8, some compatibility tests aren't needed anymore, making jQuery lighter and faster. Overall performance can be improved by using jQuery >= 2.0 instead of 1.x if you don't need to support older browsers.

Comment: Users love websites for speed ;) That's why my jQuery-free site that loads in under half a second is so much more popular than my competition, which uses jQuery and takes 5+ seconds to load :3

Comment: It's a very detailed explanation, but a bit off topic. once you call $('#box'), the only thing jquery does is match a regex, then test one of the matche's items, and go to a special block handling the case where you only request for an ID. There is nothing about browser compliance or other stuff in this simple path...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Clients love jQuery and the like because they can pay less to get more features ;) We all hope that each clients would have an infinite budget and a well running business, but reality is, much are taking a huge risk in investing in a website. In that sense, developpers can also add more value to a project without getting Out Of [price] Range. For personnal projects or for a solid-grounded client who is ambitious, vanilla is supreme pleasure. Much like using Win32 API directly to make a tool instead of gtk/qt/fltk/sdl/etc. :)

Comment: "*document.getElementById("box"): Native method iterates over DOM elements*". It doesn't even have to. UAs must keep a *hash-map* of named elements in the document. So getElementById doesn't iterate, it's just a lookup. [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51491646/3702797)

Comment: @Kaiido I just updated, thank you. Old answers, I might double check the entire thing.

Answer (score 2):

I've added another test case for `jQuery.fn.init(document.getElementById('id'))` which was faster than most other methods because it does neither parse string nor create new jQuery object (it was about 50% behind getElementById, [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jqueryspeed/2)), and when I see the source of jquery code that executes during `jQuery.fn.init` call:

```
function (selector, context, rootjQuery){
  if (selector.nodeType) {
          this.context = this[0] = selector;
          this.length = 1;
          return this;
  }
}
```

I can only conclude that Chrome and Firefox engineers did very good job at optimizing native DOM operations.